# Why does a surface contain smooth curves of arbitrary high genus?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective connected surface over $\mathbb{C}$. It is a consequence of Bertini's theorem that $X$ contains, for every $g\in \mathbb{N}$, a smooth projective connected curve of genus at least $g$.

I am looking for a direct elementary proof of this fact, i.e., a proof I can explain to someone who just started doing algebraic geometry. (I am looking to avoid sections of line bundles, for example.)

I tried choosing an embedding into a projective space and to use intersections of $X$ with hypersurfaces, but how can I guarantee the smoothness and the increase of genus using, say, Riemann-Hurwitz?

Comment: Roughly, your intersections with higher degree hypersurfaces will be branched covers of the curves that arise as hyperplane sections, so you should at least expect the genus to increase by Riemann-Hurwitz. For smoothness, I don't know that you can avoid Bertini.

Comment: What is the section of line bundles argument? It sounds interesting